# Change specific component in nested list from string to float

Tags: python, list

I have a nested list of strings. I want to change the first component of the nested list to integer, second to float.

```
>>> mylist = [['1','2','3'],['5','6','7']]
>>> datl3 = [[int(x) for x in line[0]] + line[1:] for line in mylist]
>>> type(datl3[0][0])
<type 'int'>
>>> 
>>> # turn second element to float
... datl4 = [line[0] + [float(x) for x in line[1]] + line[2] for line in datl3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

How I can I change the second component to float?

Answer (score 2):

You can use fancy unpacking to do this:

```
>>> mylist = [['1','2','3'],['5','6','7']]
>>> [[int(first),float(second),*rest] for first, second, *rest in mylist]
[[1, 2.0, '3'], [5, 6.0, '7']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using *list comprehension*

```
l = [[int(i[0]), float(i[1]), i[2]] for i in l]
```

> ```
> [[1, 2.0, '3'], [5, 6.0, '7']]
> ```